# RelativeLayout - Adjusting Position of a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am playing with the tutorial from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/.

First Activity consists of a `TextView` and a `Button`.

The `Button` sends to a second activity.

Second Activity consists of a `TextView` created programmatically and displays the message from the first `TextView`.
The `View` has a relative layout.

I want the `TextView` to span the width of the parent and the height of the content, and to be at the top of the `View`.  I also want to center the text.

```
---------
-  xxx  -
-       -
-       -
-       -
-       -
---------
```

The text is at the right place. But if I change the background color of the `TextView`, and all the "View" gets the color.  Is that expected?

Just to be on the safe side?

- The `layout*` parameters will adjust the `TextView` inside the `View`.
- The `gravity` parameter will adjust the text inside the `TextView`.

---

Also following the tutorial, I didn't modify the initial XML, which include a `TextView` with "Hello World" centered in the `View`.  Where is the TextView now?

In the Eclipse IDE :

```
---------
-       -
-       -
- Hello -
-       -
-       -
---------
```

During Execution:

```
---------
-  xxx  -
-       -
-       -
-       -
-       -
---------
```

The relevent code :

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setId(1);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setText(message);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    textView.setLayoutParams(lay);

    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
```

Thanks

Comment: "Programatically" should have been emphasized more.  There is really no answer except "Go read on the different layouts Types".  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I want the TextView to span the width of the parent and the height of the content, and to be at the top of the View. I also want to center the text.

Set the Textview's properties:

- layout_width = match_parent
- layout_height = wrap_content
- layout_gravity = top
- gravity = center_horizonal

> Just to be on the safe side?
>
> The Layout Parameters will adjust the TextView inside the View. The
>   Gravity Parameter will adjust the text inside the TextView.

Layout parameters will adjust the TextView inside the **parent** view, yes.
Gravity parameter is correct.

Just in case you missed it since you are just starting [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) is the reference for TextView.

> Also : Following the tutorial, I didn't modify the initial xml, which
>   include a TextView with "Hello World" centered in the View. Where is
>   it now?

/res/layout/activity_main.xml should be I believe.

(Small tip: try asking just one question or at least all your questions together in one place, you will generally get better answers that way.)